# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll, stuck

Tags: c#, calculator

Making a calculator to try and get used to coding in C# using Visual studio. I'm almost there but get the error message shown in the title when I try to press two symbols (i.e. `**`). How can I stop this from happening and stop the user being able to enter two symbols? I tried through the booleans saying `false` or `true` but have become a bit stuck!

```
namespace Calculator_Assignment
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Boolean Decimalcick = true;
        Boolean Plusclick = true;
        Boolean Multiplyclick = true;
        Boolean Devisionclick = true;
        Boolean Subtractclick = true; 

        float num, ans;
        int count;

        private void Button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;          //adds the numbers into the screen when clicked
            Screen.Text = Screen.Text + button.Text;
            Screen.ForeColor = Color.Red; //text that entered appears red

            Decimalcick = true;
            Plusclick = true;
            Multiplyclick = true;
            Devisionclick = true;
            Subtractclick = true;
        }

        private void operatorclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;            //adds the symbols into the screen when clicked
            Screen.Text = Screen.Text + button.Text;  //all symbols are under button_click so i do not have to repeat the code over/
        }

        private void Clearclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Screen.Clear(); //when clicked clears the screen
            Result.Clear(); //when clicked clears the result 

            Decimalcick = true;
            Plusclick = true;
            Multiplyclick = true;
            Devisionclick = true;
            Subtractclick = true;
        }

        private void Decimalclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Screen.Text = Screen.Text + "."; //adds decimal point to screen when/if clicked 
            Screen.ForeColor = Color.Red; //decimal point appears red

            Decimalcick = false;
            Plusclick = false;
            Multiplyclick = false;
            Devisionclick = false;
            Subtractclick = false;
        }

        private void Closebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close(); // closes the application down 
        }

        private void plusclick(object sender, EventArgs e) //addition
        {
            num = float.Parse(Screen.Text);
            Screen.Clear(); //clears the screen of everything
            Screen.Focus(); //textbox is focused upon when the screen is cleared
            count = 1; //this counts the store case
            Result.Text = num.ToString() + "+"; //this puts the text onto the top text box

            Decimalcick = false;
            Plusclick = false;
            Multiplyclick = false;
            Devisionclick = false;
            Subtractclick = false; 
        }

        private void multiplyclick(object sender, EventArgs e) //multiply 
        {
            num = float.Parse(Screen.Text);
            Screen.Clear(); //clears the screen of everything
            Screen.Focus(); //textbox is focused upon when the screen is cleared
            count = 3; //this counts the store case
            Result.Text = num.ToString() + "*"; //this puts the text onto the top textbox

            Decimalcick = false;
            Plusclick = false;
            Multiplyclick = false;
            Devisionclick = false;
            Subtractclick = false; 
        }

        private void divideclick(object sender, EventArgs e)  //divide
        {
           num = float.Parse(Screen.Text);
           Screen.Clear(); //clears the screen of everything
           Screen.Focus(); //textbox is focused upon when the screen is cleared
           count = 4; //this counts the store case
           Result.Text = num.ToString() + "/"; //this puts the text onto the lab

           Decimalcick = false;
           Plusclick = false;
           Multiplyclick = false;
           Devisionclick = false;
           Subtractclick = false; 
        }

        private void subtractclick(object sender, EventArgs e) //subtract
        {
           num = float.Parse(Screen.Text);
           Screen.Clear(); //clears the screen of everything
           Screen.Focus(); //textbox is focused upon when the screen is cleared
           count = 2; //this counts the store case
           Result.Text = num.ToString() + "-"; //this puts the text onto the label

           Decimalcick = false;
           Plusclick = false;
           Multiplyclick = false;
           Devisionclick = false;
           Subtractclick = false; 
        }

        private void equalsclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (count) //initalising switch statement 
            {
                case 1:
                     ans = num + float.Parse(Screen.Text);//Adding numbers 
                    Result.Text = ans.ToString();         //this converts my answer from a float to a string
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ans = num - float.Parse(Screen.Text); //Subtracting numbers
                    Result.Text = ans.ToString();         //float to a string 
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ans = num * float.Parse(Screen.Text);  //Multiplying numbers
                    Result.Text = ans.ToString();          //float to a string 
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ans = num / float.Parse(Screen.Text); //Division of numbers
                    Result.Text = ans.ToString();         //float to a string
                    break;
                default:                                  //the default figure
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to each operator button handler:

```
if("+-/*".Contains(Result.Text[Result.Text.Length - 1])) return;
```

This will prevent any operators from being clicked if the last valid click was an operator.

Comment: thank you but it's still not happy with 'num = float.Parse(Screen.Text);'

Comment: You need to check Screen.Text with the above code the exact same way as Result.Text in your handlers.  That goes in equalsclick(...).

Comment: just tried that and it still doesn't like ' num = float.Parse(Screen.Text);' brings up that message every time :(

Comment: What precisely is in Screen.Text when it bombs?

Comment: i have two text boxes, above one another. One is supposed to show the calculation then when the equals button is pressed the result should be shown  in the result box which is the top text box  but instead when an operation such as * is pressed the calculation is transferred to the top line along with the operation symbol used ( which i dont want to happen ) and then when i click equals the answer is displayed on the bottom line (called screen) and the last known button pressed is displayed in the top box ( result )

Comment: You need to remove the operation symbol manually in your code from the bottom text box when moving it to the top text box..

Comment: How would i go about that, sorry?

Comment: Using the .Remove method on the string.

Comment: ahhh, i'm quite a novice with C# and not familiar with the remove method

Comment: i think i'll leave it not sure where to implement it and how to put it but i do appreciate your help!